# The virus in my wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

The virus in my wallet, when I transfer eth,my wallet will be emptied and the eth will be transferred to an unknown address.
I want to know if geth is running correctly，
and I don't know what it is 
"auto geh"
I'm pretty sure I didn't start it
In fact, I don't know where there is a problem, it seems to be all right
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `auto geth` you see is from your `grep` command. It's added in automatically to give colour to your `grep` output on Ubuntu and other Linux distributions.  Also, I have no idea how to backtick on an iOS keyboard :/ found it :D

Your problem may be that you have your RPC address set to 0.0.0.0. This means any computer that can connect to yours can issue commands. Normally, if your accounts are locked, you're somewhat safe. But if you unlock your account (such as to send ether), it can be drained. You should leave the RPC address at its default of 127.0.0.1 (only your own computer or anything tunnelled in can connect). 0.0.0.0 is less of an issue if you are behind a properly configured firewall and you trust every machine on your local network; I still wouldn't recommend it, though.

Comment: I found that it was safe to unlock an account when rpcaddr was 127.0.0.1, but if my system and wallet system were no longer together, would I have to set the rpcaddr to 0.0.0.0? What's the solution？

Comment: You should use a tunnel (like one established through ssh) or a private bridge. For a private bridge, you can set up your own VPN (I recommend doing it on the Ethereum node itself) and setting the RPC address to the VPN-facing address. The ssh tunnel is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score -1):

Помогите решить проблему с адресом

0x957cD4Ff9b3894FC78b5134A8DC72b032fFbC464

На мой кошелек поступают средства и автоматически переводятся на этот адрес! Не зависимо от того в сети я или нет!

Помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: Hi there, could you please write your answer in english?

Comment: Help solve the problem with the address

0x957cD4Ff9b3894FC78b5134A8DC72b032fFbC464

Funds arrive in my wallet and are automatically transferred to this address! Regardless of whether I'm online or not!

Help me please !!!