# What about the theft of eth？

Tags: transactions, ether, accounts

I need help, and every time I unlock an account. my account will be transferred to someone else's accoun. at 0x957cd4ff9b3894fc78b5134a8dc72b032ffbc464[this address trading records](https://etherchain.org/account/0x957cd4ff9b3894fc78b5134a8dc72b032ffbc464#txreceived)
I found that the account was so much eth that I was not alone.
I need some way to solve this problem

I found that it was safe to unlock an account when rpcaddr was 127.0.0.1, but if my system and wallet system were no longer together, would I have to set the rpcaddr to 0.0.0.0?
What's the solution

Comment: Do you have RPC address set to 0.0.0.0?
If yes, look at [there](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23506/the-virus-in-my-wallet").

Comment: I'd consider the private key is compromised and generate a new one. From the comments https://etherscan.io/address/0x957cd4ff9b3894fc78b5134a8dc72b032ffbc464#comments it appears to belong to someone exploiting unprotected geth nodes, or an scam wallet.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like either there's malware on your computer, or your node is exposing its RPC API to other computers on your LAN or on the internet, and one of those is spending your money.

If you've got any ETH left worth protecting, I'd suggest setting up on a clean computer (preferably freshly installed) and copying the wallet files over to it, then moving any funds in the old wallet to new addresses.

As for money that's already gone, unfortunately it's unlikely that you'll be able to get it back, unless the police somewhere catch the thief and make them restore the funds, which doesn't seem to happen very often.

Comment: I have installed in the different system geth (a ubunto, a window), but the problem is not solved, when I unlock the account, all will be lost money in my account, and no tips, I think it is very dangerous